# Finding the Vector Equation of a Plane

Tags: linear-algebra

- Note: Both Question and Solution are provided, I need clarification (bottom page).

[image]

[image]

- Question: 
  Based on the provided solution available online, could you please explain why do we use the unitary vectors j and k? Why not the unitary vector i(1, 0, 0) for finding the vector equation of the plane? For example, x = P + ti ?

The reason why I think like that is because if we assume unitary vector i to be the normal vector (n) to the plane, any vector equation of a plane parallel to the normal vector n will result in a plane perpendicular to a surface (it can be an axis or another plane). Am I thinking right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit vector $\mathbf{i}=\langle1,0,0\rangle$ is **normal** (perpendicular, orthogonal) to the plane. Using it we can set up a so-called *standard* equation of the plane: if $P_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point in the plane and $\mathbf{N}=\langle A,B,C\rangle$ is a vector normal to the plane, then its equation is
$$A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0)+C(z-z_0)=0,$$
which can be further simplified to $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$. In this example, we have an initial point $P_0(1,1,3)$ and a normal vector $\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{i}=\langle1,0,0\rangle$, so we would get
$$1(x-1)+0(y-1)+0(z-3)=0 \quad \text{or} \quad x=1.$$
This would be a correct equation of the desired plane… except for it's not in the required *vector* form.

So that's your mistake: to use a single vector to set up an equation of a plane (in $\mathbb{R}^3$), you need a normal vector, and you'd end up with a *standard* equation, and it could be fine — but that's not what you're asked to set up in this question.

Also, what you're suggesting is wrong for yet another reason: in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a vector equation of the form $\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{r}_0+t\mathbf{v}$ describes a **line**, not a *plane*, because (informally speaking) such an equation describes all points obtained by moving from $\mathbf{r}_0$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{v}$ only, i.e. along only a line. To create a **plane**, you have to allow moving in two different directions, so a vector equation of a plane has to be of the form
$$\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{r}_0+t_1\mathbf{v}_1+t_2\mathbf{v}_2,$$
where $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ are two vectors **lying in the plane** (not normal to it).

So that's what the solution says: we need to find two vectors lying in the plane, and from the provided description we see that $\mathbf{i}=\langle1,0,0\rangle$ and $\mathbf{j}=\langle0,1,0\rangle$ are in it, so they would do the job. Using the given point and these vectors we can set up the desired vector equation of the plane.

Comment: "a vector equation of the form r(t)=r0+tvr(t)=r0+tv describes a line, not a plane" and "To create a plane, you have to allow moving in two different directions, so vector equation of a plane has to be of the form
r(t)=r0+t1v1+t2v2" helped to understand it. I couldn't have asked for a better explanation @zipirovich, thanks :)

Comment: @Kourosh: You're very welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

the equation of a plane is given by $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$ since the plane is perpendicular to the x- axes  we have
$$x+d=0$$ ( since the vector $\vec{n}=[1,0,0]$ is a normal vector) plug in the coordinates of the given Point we get
$$d=-1$$ and your equation is $$x-1=0$$ 
a vector equation can be
$$\vec{x}=[1;1;3]+s[0;-1;-1]+t[0;1;2]$$ where $s,t$ are real numbers

Comment: I agree with the equation of the plane, but your answer seems contradictory to what is provided for solution. It also does not follow standard unit vectors like i, j, and k?

Comment: is x - 1 = 0 the vector equation of the plane ?

Comment: aha where is the contradiction to what the OP said?

Comment: ok the vector equation is missing

Comment: could you please provide the vector equation, i want to know how it is achieved comparing to the online solution, thanks :)

Comment: you must choose three Points which are situated in the plane

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66509/discussion-between-kourosh-and-dr-sonnhard-graubner).

Comment: Since the x-axis is perpendicular to the plane, x does not change.  Parametric equations for the plane are x= 1, y= s, z= t.  The "vector" equation for that is $\vec{P}(s, t)= \vec{i}+ s\vec{j}+ t\vec{k}$

Comment: @user247327, yes , but for finding the vector equation of the plane, shouldn't we consider vector i = (1, 0 , 0), so x = x0 + ti ? because the plane is perpendicular to the normal vector i. If you can clarify this for me, I will understand everything :)

Comment: or do you mean we have to use the unitary vectors that are parallel to a plane in order to find the vector equation ?

Comment: I wouldn't say you [b]have to[/b] use unit vectors.  Any two vectors in the plane would work (the calculations are slightly simpler with perpendicular unit vectors).

Comment: ok thanks for your clarification, also @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, thank you for your explanation.